# Redirect URLs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, redirection, chromium, google-chrome-extensions

Is there any extension to Chrome that will let me *force* a URL from a particular domain to be redirected to another domain?

(E.g. Redirect `http://www.google.com` to `https://encrypted.google.com`.)

**Note**: I'm looking for an *arbitrary* redirector, **not** KB SSL Enforcer, which only works for the specific task of redirecting to HTTPS.

Comment: You could also consider using the HOSTS file as another method.

Comment: @Synetech: Would that redirect just the root page, or anything with a particular domain?

Comment: It would redirect the whole domain (or subdomain as the case may be).

Comment: @Synetech You're confusing redirecting with resolving, changing the IP address that an address resolves to will not work in this case. He wants to redirect to a different domain, not try to load that domain name on the wrong web server.

Comment: @JustinBuser, *> You're confusing redirecting with resolving*   No, I'm, not. Under certain circumstances, there is no difference. I use the HOSTS file to redirect all ads to a local web-server that is set up to accept any URL and replace pages with a small tiny bit of HTML that simply says `[ad]` and pictures that are a single transparent pixel. In other words, the ad sites are redirected to localhost (though they easily could be redirected to another machine).

Comment: @JustinBuser, *>  changing the IP address that an address resolves to will not work in this case. He wants to redirect to a different domain, not try to load that domain name on the wrong web server*   He has not indicated what the actual domains he wants to redirect from/to are (he used Google as an *example*), so it may or may not work. That's why I said he could **consider** it as a *comment* and not an *answer*.

Comment: @Synetech _No, I'm, not. Under certain circumstances, there is no difference_ You're just wrong, they are two COMPLETELY different things. Putting an entry in your hosts file pointing Domain A to IP X changes what Domain A RESOLVES to, that does not REDIRECT anything because it never goes to the original IP.  REGARDLESS, that WOULD NOT solve anything, putting an entry for www.google.com with the IP address for encrypted.google.com into your hosts file would result in Chrome trying to load www.google.com from the wrong IP, it would not REDIRECT (i.e. the address would remain www.google.com)

Comment: @JustinBuser, it *would* redirect the browser from the original IP to the specified IP. Imagine digging a ditch to re-route water. You dig a ditch, open the dam, then the water goes to the new spot instead of where it would have gone. I never said anything about 302, so you are only arguing semantics.

Comment: I had no idea https://encrypted.google.com existed! Cool

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had built a Chrome extension which does this.

<sup>Note: I built this for just 2 sites - just for the heck of it - by no means it's professional quality™. Please don't flame me for crappy code :)</sup>

Edit: Updated to manifest v2, which brings in certain additional restrictions.

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "URL Redirect",
  "version": "0.2",
  "description": "Checks URL and redirects as required.",
  "background": { 
     "page":"bg.html"
     },
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
     "js": ["content.js"]
   }
   ],
  "permissions": ["tabs"]
}
```

---

`bg.html`

```
<html>
  <script src="redirect.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

`redirect.js`

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender) {
        chrome.tabs.update(sender.tab.id, {url: request.redirect});
    });
```

---

`content.js`

```
var pattern=/\bBlocked/;
var viewtext_base_url = "http://viewtext.org/article?url=";
var newurl;
if (pattern.test(window.document.title)) // if it matches pattern defined above
{
  newurl = viewtext_base_url + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({redirect: newurl}); // send message to redirect

}
```

---

To install this,  create files with filenames as mentioned above the codeblock.

[image]

Once all 3 files are created, Click on  Chrome Menu → Tools → Extensions. Click the "+" on Developer Mode. Click on Load Unpacked extension and point to the directory where the files are stored.

[image]

Edit the files are required, and uninstall and reinstall the extension as mentioned above

Comment: Omg cool! How do I install it? (Sorry I have no experience with developing Chrome extensions, haha.)

Comment: @Mehrdad expanded the answer

Comment: ofcourse, if you aren't looking at editing the files, I could've packed the files in to a Chrome Extension....

Comment: Beautiful, thank you so much! It teaches me some JavaScript too! :D

Comment: welcome! I had developed this to learn Chrome extension development. (and to get around *cough*websense*cough*).

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed to get around the NYTimes paywall...

Comment: Thanks! BTW, is there a way to debug in chrome the script that is in bg.html?

Comment: @YossiFarjoun Yes, you log to error console using [console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/q/217957/92837)

Comment: Note, I tried this and you don't actually need to use a bg.html for this plugin.  You can just assign 'window.location = newurl' instead of doing the message passing.  Maybe that wasn't true on older versions of Chrome?

Comment: @apenwarr You need to go the content script way to inject the code to analyse the page, and at least earlier, `window.location` wasn't possible. Refer to my [so] question [How do I redirect to a URL using a Google Chrome Extension & Content Script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4859689).  `window.location = newurl` was my first approach while writing this, maybe something's changed since then

Comment: Perhaps this has changed recently.  It worked for me in Chrome 16/17.

Comment: @apenwarr are you doing a simple redirect or are you checking for conditions (as in if you're on domain x & so on)? Can you post a pastebin of your code?

Comment: Can it be used to edit the URL of CSS/JS the webpage is trying to load?

Comment: @Nakilon no, that wont be possible

Comment: Although this looked promising, none of this seems to have any effect for me. Maybe Chrome changed.

Answer (score 19):

I know I am a bit late in the game to answer this question Still I would like to answer this for future readers. Have a look at

### [Requestly](https://requestly.io) - Open Source Chrome Extension to modify Network Requests.

**Github Repo** - https://github.com/requestly/requestly

Currently, You can set up rules for

1. **Redirect** a request URL to another url.
2. **Block** some requests.
3. **Replace** some part in the URL with another string. (Even the whole URL can be replaced)
4. **Add/Remove/Modify** Headers in HTTP(s) Request and Response.
   You can set up Header Modification Rules only for specified URLs now.

Screenshots for more understanding:

- List of Rules

> [image: List of Rules]

- List of Rule Types

> [image: List of Rule Types]

- New Redirect Rule

> [image: Creating a Redirect Rule]

There are a lot of things in the roadmap to be covered like

- Setting custom headers (Done)
- Switching User Agents
- Setting parameters in request (Done)

.. and a lot more.

PS: I have created this So you can blame me if you do not find this helpful :)

Comment: Headers Modification is now present in Requestly.

Comment: This is an awesome extension! I logged in just so I can give you a +1, hopefully more people find out about it :)

Comment: Regex Support is also available in Requestly

Comment: @sachinjain024 the link to github repo is dead as of now.

Comment: @AndreiKucharavy Updated the answer as well and there you go - https://github.com/requestly/requestly

Answer (score 9):

I have developed a pre packaged user friendly redirector called [Switcheroo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg) if you're interested:

> Setup custom redirect rules for any http request i.e pages, scripts, images etc. Uses a simple string replace to do this.
>
> [image]

Comment: Open source? :)

Comment: Too bad Switcheroo doesn't support switching HTTP schemes (as indicated in the example in the question).

Comment: Also too bad it needs permission to "Read and change all your data on the websites you visit" just to redirect.

Answer (score 4):

A bit late, but this extension should surely do the trick:
[Redirector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lacckjdlmkdhcacjdodpjokfobckjclh).

And it's *an arbitrary redirector*.

Comment: Works great to avoid the Facebook start page, Match: http?://www.facebook.com, Substitute:(.*), Replacement:https://www.facebook.com/messages

Comment: oh no, it's been removed?  looked great from the screenshots! (regexes and such, which is what I need)

Comment: https://einaregilsson.com/redirector/