# Is it possible to auto-run an extension for all new Chrome windows created?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, google-chrome-extensions

I've finally found an extension that does what I want for new Chrome windows, called "ResizeWindow".  It fixes that problem that new Chrome windows other than the initial one are not opened in the top-most, left-most corner of the viewable area.

My only further desire is to be able to automatically have the extension activate upon the creation of each new window, instead of manually clicking the extension's icon in the bar after the newly opened window loads in the incorrect location.

I'm NOT a programmer, but am no dummy either (have some web authoring under my belt from the IIS5 days).  Is there a way to either edit the local copy of the extension to do this or to inject the call to the extension into whatever code (whatever makes the right-click context menu) is used for opening a link in a new window (or am I stuck waiting for someone to come up with what I want separately)?

If I need to supply any specific information, please let me know what you'd need and I will gladly do so.

Here's a little more detail: I have the [Resize Window extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh). I've removed all unwanted resolutions from the settings, so that the only one available is the matching my screen real-estate, and set the option to cycle thru the listed resolutions (only one to use means it will be default).

**However,** in order to make the extension work it's magic, you have to click the icon in the bar.  What I want to do is alter the extension somehow so that the extension fires whenever a new instance of Chrome is opened, for any reason, with no user interaction, using the settings already entered.  I doubt I'm alone in wanting this, since Chrome opens new windows in a continuing cascade, instead of always opening at top/left corner, and this alteration would simply automate the resizing without any added clicks.

Answer (score 1):

> there a way to either edit the local copy of the extension to do this or to inject the call to the extension into whatever code (whatever makes the right-click context menu) is used for opening a link in a new window (or am I stuck waiting for someone to come up with what I want separately)?

Yes, the Chrome extension source files are basically HTML/CSS/JS files and you can find them in

```
%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh
```

folder. Examining the `manifest.json` should tell you what source files are used, and you can alter them as you need. Once the extension gets updated by the author, however, the local copy will be updated, so you might want to use a different name and use the Developer tools to pack [the extension on your own](https://superuser.com/questions/284110/redirect-urls-in-chrome/284144#284144)..