# How to auto-redirect browser URL to another page?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer-9, hosts-file, firefox

What I want: When users type a certain URL, say, reddit.com or cracked.com, that they get automatically redirected to another site... say khanacademy.org or something.

I am volunteering at my local library setting up some computers and they wanted to "encourage" the kids to visit certain sites over other ones.  Ethics aside, I was wondering how I should go about implementing this other than a ban in the hosts.txt file.

PS -- Did I say I was a monster for banning Reddit from kids?  Yes yes, sorry again... just think of me preventing kids from making more inane rage comics, novelty accounts, and pun threads to fill the site. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: If you're looking at a Chrome extension here's my answer to a similar question http://superuser.com/q/284110/4377

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the easier way is to use the [hosts](http://winhelp2002.mvps.org/hosts.htm) file, it's easy to circumvent if you know the IP of the site you want to go to. Another option is http://www.opendns.com/.

Comment: But: the hosts file will only work if the target site is not on some shared hosting. Like `ping gmail.com` might yield `74.125.79.18`, but lacking the HTTP `Host:` header, `http:\\74.125.79.18` will take one to Google Search instead: http:\\74.125.79.18 (Okay, 6th edit: no IP addresses allowed in links in comments?)

Comment: I couldn't find information about *redirecting* on OpenDNS. (Even then: it's a nice solution for schools, even more if one can set up something in a router, to outsmart the kids!)

Comment: @Arjan - I'm pretty sure you can redirect a url when you block it.

Comment: Hrm, so does it have to be IP dependent?  Say if I want to direct to a specific page instead of just the base site?

Comment: @Binary - Yes for a quick solution I'm afraid so.

Comment: Oh wells... for a more complicated solution, is there a way to direct it to a more specific page?  (Say a Terms of Use page in a site?)  That was the library's first request, but understandably I'll opt for something easy if the harder option is a LOT more work.

Comment: @Binary - The correct way to handle this is to set up a proxy server for the library. Then you have full control of all the traffic. But take a better loo at the free openDNS solution, it might be enough.

Comment: Okay -- yeah I'll prolly start with the hosts.txt file and Google up the correct way to handle it.  :)

Comment: for some reason google chrome ignores your hosts file; at least under windows ...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is to put the hostname in your hosts file with the ip address of the site you want to redirect it to.

Answer (score 0):

As @Arjan pointed out in his comment, the hosts solution does not work for sites that are behind a CDN or in a shared hosting. Another solution is to use a browser extension, for Chrome, you can use the `webRequest` API:

**background.js**:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
  return { redirectUrl: 'https://bar.com'};
}, {urls: ['https://foo.com/']}, ['blocking']);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "redirect",
  "description": "Redirect foo to bar.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "https://foo.com/"],
  "background": { "scripts": ["background.js"] },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Put these two files in a folder and load the extension by going to `Chrome > Settings > Extensions > "Load unpacked extension"`, and select the directory where the files are.

Comment: I got this error: `The 'webRequest' API cannot be used with event pages.`