# Change a particular url if found in any web page in chrome to my custom url

Tags: browser

I am browsing a web page and it include a web url say http://abc.com/test/test.abc
now i want browser to change the url and look for the resource at my Custom URL http://mydomain.com/test.abc

Comment: This is not possible - you would have to create your own plugin since this is such a bespoke request I doubt anyone else will!

Comment: If you're looking at a chrome extension you can do a redirect request [Redirect URLs in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/284110/284144#284144)

Answer (score 1):

To change it in Chrome would require an extension.  I am not aware of any way that do that specifically.

However, there is a solution that would have the same end result, but not the desired effect of changing the URLs text.

You can accomplish this by editing the hosts file.  The hosts file lets you map an existing IP, hostname, of DNS name to one of your choice.

The advantage of editing the hosts file is that it will work on any connection made by your machine.  It takes precedence over DNS, and even a direct IP connection.

Here is a simple [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/) on editing a hosts file in Windows and Linux.

Comment: But I don't want to change the complete site I just want to change it for a resource a single file form that domain it is possible?

Comment: you can actually do that using Chrome extension, check my previous answer [Redirect URLs in Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/284110/284144#284144) @Champ